# Build Phonegap App is not initializing the google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

Specs:

1. PhoneGap Desktop App v0.4.3
2. Android v5.1.1

The above code is working fine with Desktop app, and the config.xml is created by that PhoneGap Desktop App.
And when i tried it on build.phonegap.com, Google maps failed to initialize, so, nothing appears on android, just a white screen.

Here is my **initMap** method which the API needs:

```
var map, directionsService, directionsDisplay;

function initMap() {

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: 25.0115052, lng: 66.7845126 },
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


} // initMap() ends
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld"
    version="1.0.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @henrisycip  I think, I should remake the problem (a simple app that just shows the google maps without any modification). I will edit the above query, after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Following are the points which are necessary to remember while making <strike>native</strike> hybrid apps:**

1. Version support of Web Languages (HTML, CSS, JS, ...) in the targeted device (Android, IOS, etc).
2. Load the required plugin / libraries to work with native components.

**Solution:**

you need **cordova-plugin-whitelist** plugin to access the maps, so, that will solve your problem:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.2" />
<!-- Allow geo: links to open maps -->
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

According to [Cordova Docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html#intent-whitelist):

> By default, no external URLs are allowed. On Android, this equates to sending an intent of type BROWSEABLE.